# sorting of array having both alphabets and numbers through jquery

Tags: jquery

I have an array in which I have both alphabets and numbers **I want to sort the values first alphabet ascending and then numeric ascending**.

Comment: you want?
so is there any try? or code that you write yet?

Comment: I have tried .sort() and .reverse()

Comment: set jsfiddle it will be good enough

Comment: this is the fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/bzA7k/

Comment: I want output as 5,15,Apple,Banana,Mango,Orange

Comment: but 5 and 15 in your array are strings not numbers

Comment: Could you please sort it for me that's not my concern if it is a string or number.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a custom comparison function, and that function needs to pad any digits that it finds with leading zeros so that all numbers in the string are the same length.

This will do the trick:

```
var fruits = ["Banana","5","15", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
fruits.sort(myCompFunc);

function myCompFunc(a,b)
{
    // pad digits
    var x = padNumbers(a);
    var y = padNumbers(b);

    // return comparison
    return (x>y);
}

function padNumbers(str)
{
var retVal = "";
var digits = "";
for (var i=0; i<str.length; i++)
{
    var c = str.substr(i,1);
    if (c>="0" && c<="9")
        digits += c;
    else
    {
        if (digits != "")
        {
            var l = 10-digits.length;
            for (var d=0; d<l; d++)
                digits = "0" + digits;
            retVal += digits;

            digits = "";
        }
        retVal += c;
    }
}

if (digits != "")
{
    var l = 10-digits.length;
    for (var d=0; d<l; d++)
        digits = "0" + digits;
    retVal += digits;
}

return retVal;
}
```

Can be done with regex replacing to be more succinct.

```
function padNumbers(str)
{
    return str.replace(/\d+/g, function(match) {
      return new Array(10-match.length+1).join('0')+match; });
}
```